# c# regex formats

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex format:

1. Only letters
2. With no html tags
3. With no these spesific charaters `(` and `)`

Please help.

Comment: This is doing it but not nice ...SearchBy = Regex.Replace(SearchBy, "<(.*?)>", string.Empty);
                    SearchBy = Regex.Replace(SearchBy, @"[0-9\-]", string.Empty);
                    SearchBy = SearchBy.Replace("(", "");
                    SearchBy = SearchBy.Replace(")", "");

Comment: Please add this to the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your conditions into 1 `Regex.Replace` since you just remove every match:

```
SearchBy = Regex.Replace(SearchBy, @"<[^>]+>|[0-9()-]", string.Empty);
```

Or, since you just want only letters to remain in the string, you can use

```
SearchBy = Regex.Replace(SearchBy, @"<[^>]+>|\P{L}", string.Empty);
```

The regex contains 2 alternatives joined with `|` alternation operator:

- `<[^>]+>` - A substring starting with `<`, then 1 or more characters other than `>` and then `>` (however, this might remove anything that looks like a tag but is not a tag!)
- `[0-9()-]` - A character class matching all digits from 0 to 9, and literal `(`, `)` and `-` (when `-` is at the end of a character class, we do not have to escape it.)

Or `\P{L}` that matches any non-letter.

Comment: Does it work for you or did I misunderstood your intentions?